# How to zoom container div and all its contents to a specific size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an HTML page with 100% (browser) width which have lot of contents. Contents are fixed in page and their sizes are both in pixels & percentages.
Now I need to add advertisement panel of 20% browser width. And want to **zoom the page container and all its contents INCLUDING TEXT to 80%** (like the zooming available in all web browsers but it should be an internal zooming).
Unfortunately my page is **not responsive** and I do not want to redevelop it or resize all its contents from scratch.
Is there any zooming facility available in HTML?

Comment: Google "css transform scale" if that will help

Answer (score 76, accepted):

you can use css transform property

```
     transform: scale(0.1);
     transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;
```

have a look at the zooming functionality i have created

```js
function setZoom(zoom,el) {
      
      transformOrigin = [0,0];
     el = el || instance.getContainer();
     var p = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o"],
            s = "scale(" + zoom + ")",
            oString = (transformOrigin[0] * 100) + "% " + (transformOrigin[1] * 100) + "%";

     for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
         el.style[p[i] + "Transform"] = s;
         el.style[p[i] + "TransformOrigin"] = oString;
     }

     el.style["transform"] = s;
     el.style["transformOrigin"] = oString;
      
}

//setZoom(5,document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);

function showVal(a){
   var zoomScale = Number(a)/10;
   setZoom(zoomScale,document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0])
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" min="1" max="10" value='10' step="1" onchange="showVal(this.value)" type="range"/>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: good work @subbu1191. I checked your fiddle its resizing each & everything in the container.

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of `transformOrigin = [0,0]` in your fiddle?

Comment: @ColdCerberus the tranform property in css changes the scale of the element but as the scale changes the x and y position of the element also changes to avoid this the transformOrigin property is used to make sure that the element is present in the same x and y position as before.take a look at the below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/j9roehqc/4/

Comment: @subbu Thank you for this explanation. I'm currently using this answer on my project and my current problem is trying to keep the content/child centered within the container/parent. Am I right that this `transformOrigin` will solve the problem? I'm not sure how though.

Comment: hopefully , if you can share any fiddle of your code ? can have a look

Comment: this code is super broken. how can it have so many uploads!?

Comment: @CodingYourLife wats broken in the code ? ..it does wat is asked for ? I don't see any issue in implementation

Comment: @subbu It is broken because you initially set the transformOrigin to [0,0] then you do: (transformOrigin[0] * 100) + "% " + (transformOrigin[1] * 100) + "%"; which is actually: (0 * 100) + "% " + (0 * 100) + "%"; which is always 0% 0%

Answer (score 2):

I have tried making a zoom-in and zoom-out functionality using plain HTML, CSS and Javascript have a look.`s`

https://codepen.io/ghewadesumit/pen/poJEYVG?editors=1111